# Query remote Hive Metastore from PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I am trying to query a remote Hive metastore within PySpark using a username/password/jdbc url. I can initialize the SparkSession just fine but am unable to actually query the tables. I would like to keep everything in a python environment if possible. Any ideas?

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

url = f"jdbc:hive2://{jdbcHostname}:{jdbcPort}/{jdbcDatabase}"
driver = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"

# initialize
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL Hive integration example") \
    .config("hive.metastore.uris", url) \ # also tried .config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL", url)
    .config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName", driver) \
    .config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName", username) \
    .config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword", password) \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()
```

```py
# query
spark.sql("select * from database.tbl limit 100").show()
```

```
AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;
```

Before I was able to connect to a single table using JDBC but was unable to retrieve any data, see [Errors querying Hive table from PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64073456/errors-querying-hive-table-from-pyspark/64074612?noredirect=1#comment113319149_64074612)

Comment: Looks like you're trying to query HiveServer, not the metastore itself. The metastore wouldn't use HiveDriver, it'd use Mysql, Postgres, MSSQL, Derby, or Oracle (each of which could be queried with sqlalchemy rather than Spark), and if you wanted to query HiveServer from Spark, you wouldn't use JDBC

Comment: So do I just need to change the driver?

Comment: Not really clear what you're expecting to connect to. The metastore won't have any data that's actually stored in Hive, just a bunch of metadata about the Hive tables

Answer (score 1):

The metastore uris are not JDBC addresses, they are simply `server:port` addresses opened up by the Metastore server process. Typically port 9083

The metastore itself would not be a `jdbc:hive2` connection, and would instead be the respective RDBMS that the metastore would be configured with (as set by the hive-site.xml)

If you want to use Spark with JDBC, then you don't need those javax.jdo options, as the JDBC reader has its own username, driver, etc options

Comment: Sorry new to Spark/Hive. I really just want to be able to query the tables in a Python environment instead of using DBeaver every time. What is the best way to do this with the existing info I have (url/username/password)?

Comment: If you've configured the hive-site.xml in the Spark config directory, then enableHiveSupport() on your SparkSession is all you need, then `spark.sql` would be able to query HiveServer. You don't need metastore access

Comment: Alternatively to modifying `hive-site.xml` is building `SparkConf` with necessary conf options.